# Experiencing the error: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error) on dotnet cli nuget push

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, nuget, azure-pipelines

After migrating from dotnet 5 to dotnet 6 the build pipeline is failing on `Dotnet nuget push` with the following error. We are using the Azure Devops Server 2020.1. Does this support for latest dotnet 6 or Do I need to upgrade to latest version.

```text
##[section]Starting: dotnet nuget push
==============================================================================
Task         : .NET Core
Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command
Version      : 2.174.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli
==============================================================================
[command]C:\windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
##[warning]Could not create provenance session: %s
##[warning]Failed to read storage account information : Failed to retrieve settings required for storage account information from strongbox. Both StorageAccountKeyBaseName and StorageAccountCount are needed.
[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" nuget push c:\agents\w1\68\a\abc.efg.MaxData.Models.3.7.0.nupkg --source https://tfs.abc.com/tfs/Primary/_packaging/21870199-3f81-4121-b786-82b7e2d3d1dc/nuget/v3/index.json --api-key VSTS
Pushing abc.xyz.Models.2.5.0.nupkg to 'https://tfs.abc.com/tfs/Primary/_packaging/21870199-3f81-4121-b786-82b7e2d3d1dc/nuget/v2/'...
  PUT https://tfs.abc.com/tfs/Primary/_packaging/21870199-3f81-4121-b786-82b7e2d3d1dc/nuget/v2/
  InternalServerError https://tfs.abc.com/tfs/Primary/_packaging/21870199-3f81-4121-b786-82b7e2d3d1dc/nuget/v2/ 43ms
  PUT https://tfs.abc.com/tfs/Primary/_packaging/21870199-3f81-4121-b786-82b7e2d3d1dc/nuget/v2/
  InternalServerError https://tfs.abc.com/tfs/Primary/_packaging/21870199-3f81-4121-b786-82b7e2d3d1dc/nuget/v2/ 33ms
  PUT https://tfs.abc.com/tfs/Primary/_packaging/21870199-3f81-4121-b786-82b7e2d3d1dc/nuget/v2/
  InternalServerError https://tfs.abc.com/tfs/Primary/_packaging/21870199-3f81-4121-b786-82b7e2d3d1dc/nuget/v2/ 43ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).


Usage: dotnet nuget push [arguments] [options]

Arguments:
  [root]  Specify the path to the package and your API key to push the package to the server.

Options:
  -h|--help                      Show help information
  --force-english-output         Forces the application to run using an invariant, English-based culture.
  -s|--source <source>           Package source (URL, UNC/folder path or package source name) to use. Defaults to DefaultPushSource if specified in NuGet.Config.
  -ss|--symbol-source <source>   Symbol server URL to use.
  -t|--timeout <timeout>         Timeout for pushing to a server in seconds. Defaults to 300 seconds (5 minutes).
  -k|--api-key <apiKey>          The API key for the server.
  -sk|--symbol-api-key <apiKey>  The API key for the symbol server.
  -d|--disable-buffering         Disable buffering when pushing to an HTTP(S) server to decrease memory usage.
  -n|--no-symbols                If a symbols package exists, it will not be pushed to a symbols server.
  --no-service-endpoint          Does not append "api/v2/package" to the source URL.
  --interactive                  Allow the command to block and require manual action for operations like authentication.
  --skip-duplicate               If a package and version already exists, skip it and continue with the next package in the push, if any.

##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]Packages failed to publish
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated to contain .Net Core 3.x (3.1) SDK/Runtime along with 2.1. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 3.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. 
Some commonly encountered changes are: 
If you're using `Publish` command with -o or --Output argument, you will see that the output folder is now being created at root directory rather than Project File's directory. To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[section]Finishing: dotnet nuget push
```

[image: 1]

Below is the nuget config file located at %Appdata%/Roaming\NuGet\nuget.config on build agent machine

I use the PAT credentials also but no use, getting the same error. Please someone help me on this. Its been a long time I stuck here.

Comment: this is a standard Nuget push failure, check your nuget configuration. After an upgrade it might not be defined correctly.

Comment: In questions like this it is wise to include some information on the steps that you have already attempted to resolve the issue. If the error information includes constructive feedback, like this one, then we expect that you have read that info and attempted to follow the advice that was given. Please update the post to include the steps you have taken or the trouble that you are having understanding the error response.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I just added the image of the tasks. Please can you check once. Also please help me where to check the configurations.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show if the target feed is this account or external. That is important for this issue, especially if your feed is external.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Thank for replying me. My target feed location is This organization/collection.

Answer (score 0):

`Response status code does not indicate success` is a classic connection issue when publishing to a NuGet feed.

This warning indicates that your config was not loaded at all:

> Failed to read storage account information :
> Failed to retrieve settings required for storage account information from strongbox.
> Both `StorageAccountKeyBaseName` and `StorageAccountCount` are needed.

For CLI build tasks make sure that you have defined the configuration in the correct default path, with the correct `StorageAccountKeyBaseName` and `StorageAccountCount`

> **[NuGet CLI Push Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-push)**
>
> - ConfigFile
>
>   The NuGet configuration file to apply. If not specified, `%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` (Windows), or `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config` or `~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config` (Mac/Linux) is used.

You could also modify your post build action to provide a specific link to your config file instead of relying on the default paths.

#### Update: Azure Pipelines [NuGet Push Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#publish-a-package)

If you are publishing to an external feed, then you will need to create a *[NuGet Service Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops#nuget-service-connection)* to manage the credentials. There is a more detailed walkthrough of the steps here: [How to publish NuGet Packages to MyGet from Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://docs.myget.org/docs/how-to/publish-nuget-packages-from-azure-devops-pipelines)

You could also consider using the API Key if your feed supports that (>= v3)